# MENU_CALLBACK with parent tabs

Tags: routes

I have a module with a bunch of menu-items. Is it somehow possible to show the MENU_LOCAL_TASK's when a MENU_CALLBACK is called?
The structure basically is like this:

- A normal menuitem in the user-menu
- Some local tasks
- 'test/%user_uid_optional/test2' in this example would be an overview-Page with several links as defined in in the last item.

This all works great, except I want the local tasks to be visible when the user clicks on 'test/%user_uid_optional/test2/%test'. Since I don't have breadcrumbs that's the only easy way for the user to get back to the overview page.
Any idea?

```
function test_menu(){
  $items = array();  
  $items['test/%user_uid_optional'] = array(
    'title' => 'test',
    'page callback' => 'test_whatever',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'user_view_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu',
  );

  $items['test/%user_uid_optional/test1'] = array(
    'title' => '...',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -20,
  );
  $items['test/%user_uid_optional/test2'] = array(
    'title' => 'test2',
    'page callback' => 'test_whatever_b',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => 'user_view_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => -15,
  );
  $items['test/%user_uid_optional/test2/%test'] = array(
    'title' => '...',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('test_whatever_d', 1, 3),
    'access callback' => 'user_view_access',
    'access arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind, menu_set_active_item('test/%user_uid_optional/test2') in test_whatever (last callback in example) seems to work.

Both item, 'test/%user_uid_optional' and 'test/%user_uid_optional/test2', are active and visible, and the drupal_get_form is executed, so who cares about beauty :)?

Comment: You could also send the url as a parameter to page callback